# how can i format a datediff to show hh:mm

Tags: reporting-services

I am not sure how to format a datediff to show as hours and minutes. It show as eg. 7.78

```
=DateDiff("n", Fields!StartOfDay.Value, Fields!EndOfDay.Value)/60
```

I would like this to show as eg. hh:mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no need to accommodate for anything over 24 hours this simple function will work.

```
=Format(DateAdd("n", DateDiff("n", Fields!StartOfDay.Value, Fields!EndOfDay.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm")
```

If you need to count anything over 24 hours then this will do the trick.

```
=
CStr(Int(DateDiff("n", Fields!StartOfDay.Value, Fields!EndOfDay.Value)/60)) + 
":" +
Replace(CStr(DateDiff("n", Fields!StartOfDay.Value, Fields!EndOfDay.Value) - Int(DateDiff("n", Fields!StartOfDay.Value, Fields!EndOfDay.Value)/60)*60), "0.", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to combine your `datediff` with a `dateadd` then `convert` it to a `varchar` of the desired format:

```
=convert( varchar
        , dateadd( "n"
                 , datediff("n", Fields!StartOfDay.Value, Fields!EndOfDay.Value)
                 , 0)
        , 8)
```

The above function will output a value in HH:MM:SS format. The day portion of durations longer than 24 hours, however, will lose the number of days.  To remove the seconds from the output value you can of course use the substring function to get the first 5 characters.

Comment: This code does not work when used as an SSRS expression.